# Can you use enumerate for multiple objects?

Tags: python, enumerate

I'm wondering if say I have two (or maybe even more) dictionaries defined in python with some keys and corresponding data, can I access both elements with an enumerate statement?:

```
for i, key1, key2 in enumerate(dict1,dict2)
... "do something"
```

thanks!

Comment: You can `zip` together the arguments to `enumerate` and then unpack them later.

Answer (score 6):

No, but you can do this:

```
for i, (key1, key2) in enumerate(zip(dict1, dict2)):
    # do something
    pass
```

But remember:

- A dictionary's elements are unordered, so we can't predict in which order will the keys appear - it might even change when the dictionaries grow.
- If one dictionary has more elements than the other, some of its keys won't show up in the iteration. If both dictionaries have the same size then it'll work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve. If you mean to iterate over enumerated keys only, two (or more) at a time, then you can use `zip(dict1, dict2,...)` as per [Óscar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25375231/21945). Or you could use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to handle the case of dicts with differing lengths.

If instead you want to iterate of the keys and *values* of each dictionary in sequence, then you can use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) like this:

```
from itertools import chain

for i, (key, value) in enumerate(chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items(), dict3.items())):
    # do something
    pass
```

---

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> dict2 = {'y': 25, 'x': 24, 'z': 26}
>>> dict3 = {'orange': 'orange', 'apple': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow'}
>>> for i, (key, value) in enumerate(chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items(), dict3.items())):
...     print "{}: {} => {}".format(i, key, value)
... 
0: a => 1
1: c => 3
2: b => 2
3: y => 25
4: x => 24
5: z => 26
6: orange => orange
7: apple => red
8: banana => yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want it enumerated.

Given:

```
>>> di1={'1':1, '2':2, '3':3}
>>> di2={'4':4,'5':5}
```

You can use `chain` from itertools to take them as a series:

```
>>> for i, e in enumerate(it.chain(di1.items(), di2.items())):
...    print i, e
... 
0 ('1', 1)
1 ('3', 3)
2 ('2', 2)
3 ('5', 5)
4 ('4', 4)
```

You could use `izip_longest` to take pairwise:

```
>>> for i, e in enumerate(it.izip_longest(di1.items(), di2.items())):
...    print i, e
... 
0 (('1', 1), ('5', 5))
1 (('3', 3), ('4', 4))
2 (('2', 2), None)
```